# Segmentation fault when storing hexadecimal value into register

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a class in assembly that is called from a class in C. The C class sends 2 integers as parameters but that's not relevant cause I'm getting a segmentation fault error that I don't seem to quite understand why.

Here's the relevant part of the assembly class:

.global testingclass
testingclass:

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $4, %esp               #reserves space for local variable

movl 8(%ebp), %ebx          #first argument of the function to %ebx
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx         #second argument of the function to %ecx

function:

movl $0, %eax ----------------< segmentation fault

movl 0x0000FFFF, %eax
and %bx, %ax
movw %ax, -4(%ebp)      
...
```

I signed the line that gives me the segmentation fault error when debugging. I really don't know how can a simple move command trigger a segmentation fault, but hope you can help me.

This is the debugger console output:

```
 ...
 11     movl 12(%ebp), %ecx         #second argument of the function to %ecx
(gdb) n
function() at asm.s:16
16      movl 0x0000FFFF, %eax
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
function() at asm.s:16
16      movl 0x0000FFFF, %eax
```

Comment: Well, what address is in eax?

Comment: What hardware are you using? 1. Did you setup your registers to allow you to access it and write to it? 2. Are you sure you are able to access/write to this register at all? Sometimes these questions depend on the hardware and environment. We cannot answer this without knowing your environment and possibly initialization of registers. You just gave us Assembly code without the hardware. This could work on some hardware and not others.

Comment: `movl $0, %eax` and `movl 0x0000FFFF, %eax` mean very different things. Notice the dollar sign!

Comment: You have been looking at  the wrong line.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, the eax register is supposely empty. I've tried to clean before but it does no good. I use eax because it's the register that must contain the returning value to the C class that calls this one.

Comment: As @NayukiMinase said, the problem is the missing `$` sign for `movl 0x0000FFFF, %eax`

Comment: @napkinsterror I'm using an architecture i686 with CPU mode at 32-bit. And yes, I'm pretty sure I can do it because I've done it before.

Comment: @Jester, you were right. I thought that since that was a mask I wouldn't have to use the dollar sign for values for it. Thanks a lot, completely forgot that was a number because I was so caught up about it being an hexadecimal value. Thanks to all, problem solved!

Comment: Intel syntax might make your code a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

the seg fault occurred at this instruction:

```
movl 0x0000FFFF, %eax
```

Not at this instruction:

```
movl $0, %eax
```

The reason for the seg fault is reading from address (64k-1)

The program can only read/write addresses that are available to the user space.

Since the OS is first, after the interrupt vectors, the code tried to read an address within the OS code.  The OS code is not part of the user space.